# DefaultAccessTokenConverter does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

I'm developing OAuth applicaiton. Rigth now I'm using JWT tokens and it works fine.

JWT token implementation:

```
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray())
                .getKeyPair("test");
        converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return converter;
    }

 @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        endpoints.accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }
```

But if I try using `DefaultAccessTokenConverter` instead of `JwtAccessTokenConverter` my access token endpoints always generate an error saying **Access denied**. Why isn't it working. Is that a bug? Can I use some other implementation for `TokenConverter`?

Comment: Have you tried not to configure an access token converter (instead of DefaultAccessTokenConverter)?

Comment: @Tom how can I do that?

Comment: By leaving out the `endpoints.accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());` line.

Comment: @Tom if I remove this line and use the default one, than I experience the same problem that I've described in my question